# Delete an Azure File Share Snapshot with C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I cannot find an example of deleting an Azure File Shares Snapshot using SDK 12 in C#.  There are a ton of examples for SDK 11 but none, that I can find, for SDK 12.  If anyone has a good example I would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. Basically you need to make use of [`ShareClient.WithSnapshot(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.shareclient.withsnapshot?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-shares-shareclient-withsnapshot(system-string)) to get access to a Share's snapshot.

```
var connectionString =
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
var shareName = "test";
var snapshot = "2022-07-26T13:49:01.0000000Z";
ShareServiceClient shareserviceclient = new ShareServiceClient(connectionString);
ShareClient shareClient = shareserviceclient.GetShareClient(shareName).WithSnapshot(snapshot);
shareClient.Delete();
```